# Issues using multithreading in SFML for C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, sfml

I am trying to create a separate thread while using the SFML game library. This is a very simplified example.

I'm using WSL and the libsfml-dev library. My issue is that it seems like I cannot perform certain actions using the SFML library on threads other then my main thread. For example, in the code below, I get an error if I click escape. What's supposed to happen is the program simply exits as the loop conditions fail.

If you want to run the code yourself...

to grab the library: apt-get install libsfml-dev

g++ compiler arguments: g++ test.cpp -pthread -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

// Create window object
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 800), "");

using namespace std;

void *func(void *threadid) {

    // Show thread was created
    cout << "New thread was ran." << endl; 

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        // This action kills the program and not in a nice way
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape)) { 
            window.close();
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main() {

    // Create new thread
    pthread_t threads[1];
    int val;
    val = pthread_create(&threads[0], NULL, func, (void *)1);
    
    cout << "Main thread was ran." << endl;

    // This is here so that the program doesn't exit
    while (window.isOpen()) {}

    return 0;
}
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iU1g.png)

Comment: It seems to have solved this specific problem, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

It is not uncommon to have to do all GUI updates from the main thread. It is likely that SFML is not even thread-safe. You need to communicate from your other threads to the main thread and let them do things like window.close().

If I modify your example and simply return from the second thread instead of calling window.close(), it does not crash.